# facing the issue of userInfoRestTemplateFactory' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean

Tags: java, spring-boot

I'm using the code from https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-security-oauth-example. But I get

```
org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoRestTemplateFactory' that could not be found - Bean method 'userInfoRestTemplateFactory' not loaded because @ConditionalOnMissingBean (types: org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration; SearchStrategy: all) found bean 'org.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configuration.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfiguration'   Action:  Consider revisiting the conditions above or defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.security.oauth2.resource.UserInfoRestTemplateFactory' in your configuration.
```

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer in what you are looking for, and what issues you are running into now? I recommend reading the How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable [ example ] (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) help topic and editing your question to reflect what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have created a AuthorizationServerConfiguration class, AuthorizationServerConfiguration, OauthConfig extending WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter and WebConfig extending WebMvcConfigurerAdapter, but after running server i come with the error "Parameter 0 of method restTemplate in com.phynart.cloud.oauth.OauthConfig required a bean of type 'com.phynart.cloud.oauth.UserInfoRestTemplateFactory' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'com.phynart.cloud.oauth.UserInfoRestTemplateFactory' in your configuration.
"